# Cannot update Ubuntu 14.04 : apt-get issues

Tags: 14.04, apt

I am trying to update Ubuntu 14.04. But `sudo apt-get update` is returning the following errors.

```
0% [Connecting to in.archive.ubuntu.com] [Connecting to archive
0% [Connecting to in.archive.ubuntu.com] [Connecting to archive
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Err http://archive.canonical.com trusty InRelease
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg

Could not resolve 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release.gpg

Could not resolve 'archive.canonical.com'
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
Could not resolve 'extras.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists...Done
W:Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease
W:Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg
Could not resolve 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg
Could not resolve 'archive.canonical.com'
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg
Could not resolve 'extras.ubuntu.com'
W:Some index files failed to download.They have been ignored or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Use code formatting. Then you can post the output with URLs.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing with same problem. From the errors you can see that you are using the Ubuntu Server in India. Change the update server to something other than India.
Go to **Setting** > **Software & update** --- under **Ubuntu Software** tab, find the drop-down list to choose the server for downloading updates from. Choose main server.

See this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But this solution did not work for me. I had configured internal network earlier and now I have changed it to NAT. Does this create a problem?

Answer (score -2):

#### Repository[prbm]

There is a spelling mistake on your link on **sources.list** it will be present on a directory (**/etc/apt/**). There you will be able to see the file called **sources.list** and **sources.list.save**. Manually copy the contents of file **sources.list.save** to **sources.list**. Else use following commands on terminal.(Make sure that you logged on root permission / You need to know the administrator password).

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list.save /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
```

I hope it will works fine..

Comment: Thanks for replying. The same problem still persists though.

Comment: On what basis you said 'There is a spelling mistake on your link on sources.list'? Just a guess or some clue from the errors?

Answer (score -2):

I am in Kashmir. I just updated my Ubuntu (15.10) from main server in last few min. Please give a try to updating from the main server and do update using `apt` command instead of `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt update
```

and share the error result

---

*I don't know why you removed the screenshot of the errors in your question. it was useful.*